# Grunt build not moving images

Tags: yeoman, gruntjs

I'm using Yeoman and Grunt to build my project. Everything works fine except the images folder isn't copied from the app directory to the dist directory when I run "grunt" to compile my project.

As grunt clears out the dist folder every time it builds I was wondring how you link the images folder to be part of the grunt build so it appears in the dist folder when compiled??

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed unintended behavior and will be fixed in the next release. If you want to adjust your Gruntfile to support gif files, you can take a look at [this patch](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/commit/1fc96994f2377138c4800ea784637295a1aa680f).

Answer (score 0):

Worked out why. I only had two images and both were .gifs. It seems to only work with jpgs and pngs.